# Vue.js and structuring multi-page web apps - component registrations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-page-application

I want to use Vue.js for a MVC Core 2.1 multi-page web app, but I think my approach is a bit quirky.  
I have searched a lot for a better way to structure my code. I also took a look at how PHP Laravel 5.x does it, and it seems like they take the same approach as the one I use, kinda.

#### My approach

I have created a `main.js` file where I register some of the components globablly, and the ones that are only used by specific components will of course be registered only locally. So, basically every page will have it's own component registered gloablly... (btw I use Webpack)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Axios from 'axios';

import BaseLayout from './components/layout/BaseLayout.vue';
import BaseHeaderLayout from './components/layout/BaseHeader.vue';

import HomeIndex from './components/home/Index.vue';
import HomeCreate from './components/home/Create.vue';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

window.axios = Axios; // Make axios available throughout (assign as global variable)

// Layout components
Vue.component("base-layout", BaseLayout);
Vue.component("base-header", BaseHeaderLayout);

// Home/
Vue.component("home-index", HomeIndex);
Vue.component("home-create", HomeCreate);

new Vue({
    el: "#App"
});
```

As the web app grows, I guess this file will become massive - stuffed with component registrations.  So my question is: **Is there another way to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

you can use vue-cli to structure you project (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) which is now a release candidate version and integrates webpack by default. With the command "vue create my-project" you will see a nice scaffolding of your project. In the main.js you would only put you root component.
Sorry for the bad formatting I am on mobile.

Comment: I've looked into how vue cli structures the app folders and files - it seems like it just moves the component registrations to the Vue.app component instead. All registrations will just happen in that one component instead. But perhaps that is better, in terms of not allowing components to be used globablly?

Comment: Yes I think that is the best practice, instead of using components globally you could use other strategies to handle common data (for example vuex library as explained [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html))

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is initialize a Vue app on certain parts of the page by wrapping them up in a container of sorts and then do the same for all the pages that need Vue components.

I do it this way, I have a container class called vue-container which wraps my components calls like this:

```
<div class="vue-container">
  <floating-menu></floating-menu>
  <show-pdf :resource="<%= @resource.as_json(current_user: current_user) %>"></show-pdf>
</div>
```

Here floating-menu and show-pdf are two Vue componenents.

Then, in my app.js file which is imported for all the pages, I have the following code:

```
if(window.vueapp == null){
  window.vueapp = []
}
if(window.vueapp != null){
  for(var i=0, len=vueapp.length; i < len; i++){
    vueapp[i].$destroy();
  }
  window.vueapp = []
}
var myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.vue-container');
forEach(myNodeList, function (index, element) {
  if (element != null) {
    var vueapp = new Vue({
      el: element,
      store,
      components: {
        ShowPdf, FloatingMenu
      }
    })
    window.vueapp.push(vueapp);
  }
});
```

This creates and initializes a Vue app on every `.vue-container` element and everything works!

If you need to share data among the different components, any of the standard data sharing techniques like an Event Bus or Vuex would work just fine.

I wrote a blog post detailing this setup: https://blog.koley.in/2018/vue-components-in-multi-page-apps

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vue CLI create and merge to your MVC Core project. In vue.config.js, define different entry to generate js file for each page that uses its own Vue instance. See below

```
//**
//vue.config.js
//
module.exports = {
    outputDir: './dist',
    filenameHashing: false,
    lintOnSave: false,

chainWebpack: config => {
        config.optimization
              .splitChunks(false);

        //output: ./dist/js/page1.js
        config.entry("page1")
              .add('./src/pages/page1/main.vue'); 

        //output: ./dist/js/page1.js
        config.entry("page2")
              .add('./src/pages/page2/main.vue');
}
//**
///src/page1/main.vue
//
import Vue from 'vue'
import HomeIndex from './components/home/Index.vue';
import HomeCreate from './components/home/Create.vue';

Vue.component("home-index", HomeIndex);
Vue.component("home-create", HomeCreate);

window.Vue = Vue;   //make Vue available to page


//**
//view/page1.html
//
...

<div id="app">
  ...
  <home-index />
  ...
  <home-create />
  ...
</div>
<script src="dist/js/page1.js"></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: { ... }
      ...
     });

</script>
...
```